# Derived class has base class private members

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, private

I have this problem and i keep thinking about it. I'm trying to figure how this actually works and WHY?

So, I have this Base class:

```
public class Shape 
{
  private float width;
  private float height;

  public Shape(float width, float height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  public void setWidth(float x){
    this.width = x;
  }

  public float getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public float getHeight() {
    return height;
  }
}
```

and this derived class:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape 
{
  public Rectangle(float width, float height) {
    super(width, height);
  }

  public float area (){
    float x = getHeight();
    float y = getWidth();
    return x*y;
  }
}
```

Why is the derived class using `width` and `height`?
I mean, I can instantiate objects like:

```
Shape s = new Shape(1,1);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(3,5);
```

and `Rectangle` has the variables `width` and `height`. I'm using the base class constructor, but when it passes `super(width, height)` it gets to `this.width = width` and the same for `height`.

What is `this.width`?.
Is it just a kind of copy for the base class or how does it work?

Comment: Note that in the derived class you can rename `width` & `height` to `foo` & `bar` and it will have no effect on the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding here is to notice that inside the base class constructor we have two variants of both the 'width' and the 'height' variable: one are members in the class object as such, the other are the parameters passed to the constructor, each using the same name as the other

`this.height = height;` takes the value of the constructor *parameter* and assigns it to the class *member*. It is a bit of an odd convention, but makes it easy to visually check that the constructor parameters are assigned to the correct class members during construction.

Comment: Basically, your parameters are called "width" and "height" also your variables are called "width" and "height". Putting "this." Keeps the program from getting confused. If you had named the parameters "w" and "h" then you wouldn't need the "this.". You could simply write "width = w;" Instead of "this.width = width;" but, like @Lars said, it keeps the code neater when every name makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
private float width;
private float height;

public Shape(float width, float height) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}
```

In the above code, the global variables are width, height. Similarly the local variables are also width, height present in the Shape Constructor. So we use this keyword for differentiating the local variable and global variable , as they both have the same name.